# Oracle license for development environment?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm sorry that I have to ask that here, but I haven't found a conclusive answer on the oracle page or in the internet. I've even been on the phone with a sales rep, but they couldn't help me neither.

What kind of Oracle Setups/licenses are you using for your development environments? We currently are using 10g XE which only has one significant limitation: the 4gb database size limit. Are there any other 'free' versions which don't have such limitations? And if not, what would be the most economic version/combination? The often have a hard user limit which are ridiculous low.

Thanks!
Cheers
Reto

PS. I'm not sure if I have to mention that: I'm not looking for any illegal solutions

Comment: Keep your ears to the ground, there are plans to release Oracle 11g XE sometime in the not-too-distant future, and the 4gb limit will be increased somewhat. http://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2010/09/good-news-about-oracle-xe-11g.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it appears that there exists a production environment, the license for the software you download from OTN will almost certainly not be sufficient.  Since it sounds like each developer has a local development environment, however, you should be able to make use of the Personal Edition.  This is a relatively inexpensive ($460 perpetual/ $92 for a 1-year license plus support in the Oracle Store at the moment) version of Oracle that is intended to be used by a single developer on a local machine.  It has all the functionality of the enterprise edition of the database.

Answer (score -3):

You can download Oracle Database 11g (and most other Oracle solutions) from their website [oracle.com.](http://www.oracle.com/)

All you need is to register for free, and download the application, you don't need any license if it is for personal use.

Comment: Technically, there is still a license. The download from metalink is under a "Development License"... read it carefully for the details of use, and for restrictions

Comment: The programs may be installed on one computer only, and used by one person in the operating environment identified by us. You may make one copy of the programs for backup purposes.

Comment: If your "development environment" is related to some sort of production environment, the license for the software you download from OTN is almost certainly insufficient.  The OTN license is sufficient for prototyping, but once you're talking about maintaining multiple environments, you're going to need a license from Oracle Sales.

Comment: Everything else is licensed, the customer has a two test environment and a production environment. My development environment is for dev purposes only and only used by myself. Of course we are ways past the prototyping phase, does this change anything?

Comment: "Dev purposes only" for a current production system, even if you're prototyping changes to the production system, does not fall under the development license as I understand it. I think @Justin's comment says it best. The idea behind the OTN license is to allow developers to become familiar with Oracle's features, to evaluate it for your needs, etc. It is NOT to develop code or databases for production environmnents.